# Proving $|\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)|\leq\frac{n!}{4}(\frac{b-a}{n})^{n+1}$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

My task is to prove:
$$
|\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)|\leq\frac{n!}{4}(\frac{b-a}{n})^{n+1}
$$
where $x_i=a+i\frac{b-a}{n}$ for $i=0,...,n$ and $x\in [a;b]$

I managed to prove that:
$$
|(x-x_0)(x-x_1)|\leq \frac {1}{4}(x_1-x_0)^2
$$
so it's for $n=1$, using a.m.-g.m., but I don't know in which direction to go in order to prove it for all $n$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum of error in equidistant interpolation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906714/maximum-of-error-in-equidistant-interpolation) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7C%5Cprod_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5En(x-x_i)%7C%5Cleq%5Cfrac%7Bn!%7D%7B4%7D(%5Cfrac%7Bb-a%7D%7Bn%7D)%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: yes, thank you.